# Xcode 5: Simulate app build without XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to simulate my iOS app using only the "build for profiling" build via terminal.

Here is what I am trying:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -currentSDKRoot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -SimulateDevice "iPhone (Retina 4-inch)" -SimulateApplication /Users/yonatanoren/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Path/To/App
```

The simulator opens, but my app doesn't run -- it seems like it crashes (it doesn't show up at all).

I'm using Pods with my project.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Answer here: [Installing a TestFlight app on iOS iPhone Simulator - Registration Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942477/installing-a-testflight-app-on-ios-iphone-simulator-registration-failed)

Comment: Might I ask why you try to do it without XCode?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate my app without the source code.

Comment: In order to...? I'm sorry but I don't see the point to do that

Comment: I'd like to distribute my app for testing on other computers -- not mobile devices -- without distributing my source code.

Comment: It appears that the simulator does not get its queues from the command line. Instead it is told -SessionOnLaunch NO at which point it waits for its queues from XCode. If XCode is not waiting to debug, the Simulator will just hang at a black screen. Clearly there is more to running an app on the simulator than a simple command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [testflightapp](https://testflightapp.com/)

Comment: Ah, I am looking to distribute my app for testing on the iOS simulator. NOT mobile devices. TestFlight will not work in this case.

Comment: @Yoni201 Unless you don't have an Apple developer account I would never recommend testing your app on the simulator. I would only recommend simulator for development and even then use a device where possible. The device will give completely different results to a device. Such as when I developed an app on simulator then moved to device I started getting memory warnings on device because the device had less memory.

Comment: @Yoni201 Something also will just not work. Such as dialer, messager, email etc. Basically the simulator wasn't made for testing purposes and doing testing on there will not provide correct results and because of not testing correctly you open yourself up to be rejected from the app store.

Comment: I am using it for development. This is a special circumstance. I found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942477/installing-a-testflight-app-on-ios-iphone-simulator-registration-failed

Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Yoni201 so `"I'd like to distribute my app for testing on other computers"` wasn't correct as you have now stated `"I am using it for development"`. Telling us one thing and meaning something else just means your not going to get the best possible answer.

Comment: @Yoni201 So it is for testing purposes. In which case I go back to my original comments. Not recommended at all, I have had clients who don't have phones before and I have told them out right there is no point in them testing on a simulator as it would not act the same. And they just went out and got a phone from where ever.

Comment: It's a very casual test, nothing in depth. In any other case I would certainly follow your advice. Thanks.